# How to set the same height in the inners DIV's?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maximize a floating div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996977/maximize-a-floating-div)

I have this HTML code:

```
    <div id="container">


        <div id="sidebar">

            left
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            right
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            bla bla
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
```

and this is the CSS code:

```
#container {
    width: 760px;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;   

    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;      
}

#sidebar {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    background:#555;
}

#content {
    float:left;
    width:75%;
    background:#eee;
}


.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

unfortunatly the sidebar does not have the same height as cointaner, how can I extend its height ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Might not be exactly what you are looking for but try this:

```
<style>
#container {
    width: 760px;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;   

    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;      
    position: relative; //Makes the children in the container positionable
}

#sidebar {
  bottom: 0px; //position side bar.
  left: 0px; //position side bar.
  top: 0px; //position side bar.
  width:25%;
  background:#555;
  position: absolute
}

#content {
  margin-left: 25%;
  width:75%;
  background:#eee;
}


.clear {
  clear: both;
}
</style>
  <div id="container">


        <div id="sidebar">

            left
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            right
            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            bla bla
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the background color of your container element to the same background color as the sidebar.  That way it would at least *look* like the sidebar extends to the bottom.

If you need the sidebar to *really* extend all the way down, I think the easiest way to do this would be to use a table.  There may be a way to do this using CSS, but I've searched a lot and haven't found a way.

Answer (score -2):

You have more `<br/>` in your #content then in your sidebar. So the whole #container goes by the height of the maximum div element inside which is the #content, that is why #sidebar seems smaller. Either put the same amount of `<br/>` in the #sidebar or romve the `<br/>`'s from both divs and set them both their heights e.g.

```
#sidebar{

height:100;

}

#content{

height:100;

}
```